# Python .txt content to list

Tags: python, string, text-files

I would like to open a .txt file and separate the words into separate strings in a list (e.g. ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example']).
For some reason when I attempt this, the letters are separated and I receive weird symbols and characters at the start that weren't in my original text document.

```
file = open(userFile, "r")
userInput = file.read()
file.close()
print(userInput)
```

[image: Screen shot of what I get when I run my code.]

My .txt file only contained the words 'something else' repeatedly a couple of times.

Comment: That file looks like it was saved as UTF-16 - whatever editor you used can probably be configured to use UTF-8 or plain ASCII text, which would be vastly more compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as infile:
     lines = infile.readlines()
infile.close()
words = [word.strip() for word in lines]
```

This works for many different file encodings.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl this was one year ago me knowledge haha I updated it